# Scroll to div using only text - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a list of divs that I get from a plugin that contains unique text. I have a clickable map that when clicked on certain parts, will search the page for the text and if found, should scroll to it. The code will be embedded directly in the WordPress admin edit page section. I tried using :contains(string) which finds the string

`$("div:contains('text')")`

but I don't know how to scroll to it. The multiple divs returned all have the same class name and no id so I can't access them individually. Any help or tips is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide us some code or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that someone else might know of a way that you could scroll directly to a piece of text, but generally speaking when you're writing javascript to scroll to something in a document, it's scrolling based on the offsetTop property of a container. If no two pieces of unique text will be in the same div, then you're going to need to use some regular expressions (which I'm not very strong with) to locate the first opening and closing tags containing that string. Then, you'll need to get the ID of those tags, and use the ID to find the divs offsetTop property. Depending on whether your unique text will be directly in the container you're scrolling to or not, this could become increasingly complex.

Another solution that I just realized shortly after posting this, would be that you could iterate through every element matching a pattern. If you know that your unique text will always be in a div with class "unique" and that you will never have two pieces of matching text in that div, you can iterate through all of your divs with the class "unique" with a for loop and check to see if the string is present.

Comment: OP mentioned that there are no ids as far as your comment question, you can always go to the meta site (and probably preferred) and ask there if the type of answer you're giving is acceptable)

Answer (score 0):

When you find the element it's in, you can scroll to it with this:

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return [curtop];
    }
}
```